# how can I get one document in mongoose(mongoDB)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to return one index's object of the array,
but when I query, It returns to me that all of the documents.

This is my Schema(userTb)

```
const userTbSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  userId: String,
  folders: [
    {
      folderTitle: String,
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the result of the query of my Schema(userTb).

```
{
    "_id": "5fc4c13f32ab3174acb08540",
    "userId": "go05111",
    "folders": [
        {
            "_id": "5fb7b0473fddab615456b166",
            "folderTitle": "first-go"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fb7b0473fddab615456b16b",
            "folderTitle": "second-go"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the only { "folderTitle" : "first-go" } folder's object, like...

```
{
    "_id": "5fb7b0473fddab615456b166",
    "folderTitle": "first-go"
}
```

so I query like this

```
router.get('/folder/:folderId', (req, res, next) => {
    UserTb.find({ folders : { "$elemMatch" : { _id : req.params.folderId} } })
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        res.status(200).json({
            docs
        }); 
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

but the result is nothing changed.

I tried a few different ways, but it didn't work out.

how can I fix it?
please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([live version](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OcSk5GiNRRH)):

```
UserTb.aggregate({
  $match: {
    "folders._id": req.params.folderId  }
},
{
  $project: {
    folders: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$folders",
        as: "f",
        cond: {
          $eq: [
            "$$f.folderTitle",
            "first-go"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    _id: 0
  }
})
```

It will retrieve `folders:[{...}]` this will be easy to tackle using JS, and quicker.

**Mechanism**

- Match only documents containing `_id:folderId`
- project only the inner document